# Is there a way to remove the time displayed in the scheduling end date column?

Tags: column, date-time

We've created a view of expired pages showing last reviewed date and scheduling end date.

Our last reviewed date can be formatted to just show the date, but can't seem to do this with the scheduling end date. Is there a way?

Comment: Just go to the column settings and select Show Date only instead of Date and Time

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I can do this with our last reviewed date, but not the scheduling end date - there's no option in the settings to change this.

Comment: In that case you can have a calculated column in the view which takes only date from the schedulling end date and display this calculated column and hide the schedulling end date column

Comment: OK, thanks Ankit, nice workaround. I used =IF(ISBLANK([Scheduling End Date]),"",[Scheduling End Date]) in the formula to bring across the date (not all docs have expiry date).

Comment: cool ...let me put it that as an answer...you can mark it as an answer to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option will be to go to the column settings and select Show Date only instead of Date and Time. If Settings not available you can have a calculated column in the view which takes only date from the schedulling end date and display this calculated column and hide the schedulling end date column.